# htaccess rewrite to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^findmyfiver\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.findmyfiver.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Which successfully forces a user to the `www.` version on the site; however I want to redirect a user to a specific domain and page when they enter:

```
findmyfiver.com/tester.php to findmyfiver.co.uk/tester.php
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^findmyfiver\.com$ 
# Add a rule to rewrite tester.php to a different domain
# Before your other catch-all rule
RewriteRule ^tester\.php http://findmyfiver.co.uk/tester.php [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.findmyfiver.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: That seems to work! However, I have the entire domain behind a password, how do I have this work just for this file only but keep the rest of the domain password protected?

Comment: @TheBounder I'm not sure. You should post a new question, since that's a separate issue.