# Static IP address of Openshift app

Tags: php, dns, openshift

How to find static IP address of my non scalable app(free tier). I need it for My dns management A(HOST)entry field.any rhc window command

Comment: `ping` `ping` `ping` `ping` `ping` `ping` `ping` `ping` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to set [Custom URL name for your OpenShift app](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way), I suggest editing `CNAME` record instead of hard-coding the `A` record.

1. Edit the CNAME record of your domain to point to `<app>-<namespace>.rhcloud.com`
2. Run `rhc alias add <app> <domain>` command (OpenShift creates new VHost for your domain)
3. Wait for the DNS to get propagated ([how long does it take](https://serverfault.com/questions/125371/how-long-does-it-take-for-dns-records-to-propagate))

Read [Custom URL names for your PaaS applications (host forwarding and cnames)](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way) blog post for more information.

---

If you really want to know the IP address of your app, you can print it using `OPENSHIFT_<cartridge>_IP` environment variable:

```
rhc ssh <app> 'echo $OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP'
```

See the [full list of environment variables](https://www.openshift.com/page/openshift-environment-variables) exposed by OpenShift platform.

Comment: thanks vojtech vitek , but is there is problem if i use hard coding A record.? is openshift provide dynamic IP address for app or dedicated one

Comment: vojtech i add alias www.mydomian.com and update cname. everyting is fine for home page.but poblem is when user click on any link on website.Browser URL field change from www.mydomian.com to http://myapp.rhcloud.com/link
instead of www.mydomian.com/link.How to cope this problem

Comment: @gill Imho, this blames your application, eg. it's cache? What are you actually running?

P.S.: You could use URL redirection in your application to prevent this, as the *.rhcloud.com is still a valid domain.

Comment: thanks vitek for reply i am running osclass more detail at link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823640/change-base-link-of-website-using-htaccess-file

Comment: @gill http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845442/htaccess-rewrite-to-new-domain should help you.

Comment: this will not work if you're trying to setup an `mx record` as it needs a static IP for `A record`.