# Change Base link of website using .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, openshift

can editing .htaccess file. Base address of site for all link on home page will changed?

**scenario**:My osclass hosted at openshift cloud with url http://myappdomain.rhcloud.com After adding alias at server side i am using www.mydomain.com with forwarding masking feature.Everyting is fine for home page.But poblem is when user click on any link on website.Browser URL field change from www.mydomain.com to http://myappdomain.rhcloud.com/link instead of www.mydoamin.com/link.but if user manually type www.mydomain.com/link it works and it remain same not changing to http://myappdomain.rhcloud.com/link in browser URL. Hover over links also show http://myappdomain.rhcloud.com/link not www.mydomain.com/link
i even try to edit config.php file

```
define('WEB_PATH', 'http://www.mydomain.com/');
```

but it is not working. my point is can this acheive with editing .htaccess file with minimal effect or there some other way. Have anyone try openshift for osclass before with custom domain? wordpress and osclass are quite similar  in architecture.Have wordpress users on openshift face such problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that .htaccess only changes the way server handles visitor's request. It does not change the contents in your web site. Therefore, you can never change your "hover result" with .htaccess settings.

I think that depends on how the links are generated in your website:

1. If the links are stored along with HTML in database, you'd need to change it with database query. If you're using MySQL, please learn your database structure and form a correct [REPLACE query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).
2. If the links are generated on-load, please make sure you flush all the caches. Cache may not know that your `WEB_PATH` has changed.