# Apache: When access vHost on specific port forward to another server

Tags: apache, portforwarding

I have set up a project on my local machine (Win8, XAMPP), the URL `http://local.project.com` maps to `127.0.0.1` in my `hosts` file.

When the application calls XHRs with the base URL `http://local.project.com:8080/` apache should forward this request to another server in my network (e.g. `192.168.35.16:8080`).

So for example:

`http://local.project.com/index.js` should point to `http://local.project.com/index.js`
`http://local.project.com:8080/index.js` should point to `http://192.168.35.16:8080/index.js`

How can I achieve this with Apache?

Comment: As `local.project.com` will always point to `127.0.0.1`, so i doubt it will look for web server on your network. You can follow this answer to redirect via `.htaccess`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6845527/861704

Comment: you can try mod_proxy ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180687/apache-port-forward